# Insert data in SQLite DB Table No Such Table

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I have been using the same code to insert data into a SQLite DB for two projects with NO ISSUES.
I updated VS 2019 to ver 16.11.10 Now my Code is failing. Here is a screen shot of the exception.
And the code I am using to create the DB and Tables also the Insert Into the Table code.
**Can someone explain what is not working ?**
When I open the DB with DB Browser I see Tables(0) BUT NO Error message when I run the MakeDB Sub.

```
Public Class frmMakeDB
Public connStr As String = "Data Source={0};Version=3;"
Public conn As SQLiteConnection
Private Sub btnMakeDB_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMakeDB.Click
    makeDB()
    makeTable()
    frmStart.Show()
    Close()
End Sub
Public Sub makeDB()
    If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(gv_dbName) Then
        Try
            conn = New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;")
            conn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Make DB " & ex.ToString)
            'tbMessage.Text = "DB and Tables NOT Created"
        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub makeTable()

    Dim create_table As String = String.Empty
    create_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PWInfoTable(
                    PID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                    ptWebSite TEXT,
                    ptUserName TEXT,
                    ptPass TEXT)"


    Dim dbTable As String = "PWInfoTable"

    If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(dbTable) Then
        Try
            Using conn As New SQLiteConnection(connStr)
                conn.Open()
                Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(create_table, conn)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("EXP " & ex.ToString)
            'tbMessage.Text = "PWInfo Table FAILED"
        End Try
    End If

End Sub
```

Insert Data in Table Code.

```
    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    InsertSiteData()
End Sub

Private Sub InsertSiteData()

    Using conn As New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;")
        conn.Open()

        Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand
            cmd.Connection = conn
            Try
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PWInfoTable (ptWebSite,ptUserName,ptPass) VALUES (@ptWebSite,@ptUserName,@ptPass)"

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ptWebSite", DbType.String).Value = tbWebSite.Text.Trim
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ptUserName", DbType.String).Value = tbUserName.Text.Trim
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ptPass", DbType.String).Value = tbPassword.ToString.Trim
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Insert Failed" & ex.ToString)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using

    frmStart.Show()
    Close()

End Sub
```

Screen Shot
[image: Exception]

Answer (score 0):

The REAL Issue was doing copy and paste from one project to the new project.
I defined connString but forgot to add information to the defined string.
Here is line of code missing in the form load event.

```
connStr = String.Format(connStr, gv_dbName)
```

The complete form load event.

```
Public connStr As String = "Data Source={0};Version=3;"
Private Sub frmMakeDB_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim txString As String
    txString = vbCrLf & "Click CREATE to make the Database" & vbCrLf & "and make the Database Tables"
    tbMessage.Text = txString
    connStr = String.Format(connStr, gv_dbName)
End Sub
```

**Typical COPY and PASTE Mistake Pay Attention**